# "Dont care" pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a function like this:

```
uint8_t getULEB128Value(uint8_t *p, uint32_t *to){
    unsigned int result; 
    uint8_t count = 1;
    uint8_t cur;

    result = *p;
    if(result > 0x7F){
        count++;
        cur = *(++p);
        result = (result & 0x7F) | (cur << 7);
        if(cur > 0x7F){
            count++;
            cur = *(++p);
            result |= ((cur & 0x7F) << 14);
            if(cur > 0x7F){
                count++;
                cur = *(++p);
                result |= ((cur & 0x7F) << 21);
                if(cur > 0x7F){
                    count++;
                    cur = *(++p);
                    result |= ((cur & 0x7F) << 28);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    *to = result;
    return count;
}
```

Now I just want to know the length and I'm not really interested in the value...
Is it possible to have a don’t care pointer? so every value which is wrote there goes to nirvana? like /dev/null?
I mean of course I can create a pointer somewhere and free it afterwards but maybe there is a thing for that already?

Comment: What do you really want to do ? A `sizeof(*ptr)` does the job

Comment: You are basically return size of pointer (4 or 8) in result and garbage in value. Are sure you are understand what are you doing?

Comment: i changed the function so you will see what im doing

Comment: Just wrap the function - `uint8_t getULEB128Value_only(uint8_t *p) { uint8_t dummy; return getULEB128Value(p, &dummy); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual pattern for this is to allow passing a null pointer into your function and check this before writing the value:

```
if (to != NULL) {
  *to = result;
}
```

Then you can call it like

```
result = getULEB128Value(p, NULL);
```

when you do not want to write anything into the "to" pointer.

Answer (score 2):

In C you're not legally allowed to dereference pointers not pointing to existing valid objects.

To find the length (if I correctly understood your problem) you can do something as simple as this:

```
size_t GetLength(const uint8_t* p)
{
  size_t l = 1;
  while (*p & 0x80)
  {
    p++;
    l++;
  }
  return l;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept of /dev/null doesn't apply to a pointer, because it's not a stream. If you write multiple data to a pointer, you typically increment the pointer for each value, so you actually write all but the first value behind the pointer. Because pointer aritmetics are well-defined, it is not possible to have a "don't care" pointer.